# MongoDB position of $unwind in a $match, $group, $lookup query

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i have a question regarding the position of `$unwind` in a mongo query. I could not find anything in their documentation about it, so i am asking here :) Maybe someone can explain that to me.

I have the following structure of a query

```
collection.aggregate([ 
{ '$lookup': { from: 'bill_position', localField: 'billPositions', foreignField: '_id', as: 'joined_bill_pos' } }, 
{ '$unwind': '$joined_bill_pos' },
{ '$match': { '$and': [ 
{
    $or: [
      { 'joined_bill_pos.pricelistItem.itemType': { '$in': [ // some data ..  ] } }, 
      {'joined_bill_pos.isPackage': {$eq: true}},
    ]
},
{ date: { '$gte': 1485903600000 } }, { date: { '$lte': 1582930799000 } }, 
{ closed: true }, 
{ '$group': { _id: { 
    name: '$joined_bill_pos.pricelistItem.itemType', 
    isPackage: '$joined_bill_pos.isPackage' }, 
    count: { '$sum': '$joined_bill_pos.quantity' }, 
    total: { '$sum': { '$subtract': [ '$joined_bill_pos.totalPrice', '$joined_bill_pos.discount' ] } } } } ]
)
```

which seems to work fine now, before i made the mistake and placed the

```
{ '$unwind': '$joined_bill_pos' },
```

after the

```
 { '$match': { '$and': [ ....
```

my question is, why does it work at all if the `$unwind` is after the match? And why is the result different? As additional info, `billPositions` (in the lookup) is an array of ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too was wondering what does that unwind does.Finally according to my understanding it would deconstruct the array result of the lookup into list of object result.

Execute and check result of both the query.You will get idea about it.

```
collection.aggregate([ 
{ '$lookup': { from: 'bill_position', localField: 'billPositions', foreignField: '_id', as: 'joined_bill_pos' } }
])

collection.aggregate([ 
{ '$lookup': { from: 'bill_position', localField: 'billPositions', foreignField: '_id', as: 'joined_bill_pos' } }, 
{ '$unwind': '$joined_bill_pos' }
])
```

Comment: Thanks, but that is clear to me. My question is why does it change the result if you position it differently in the query!

Comment: Because you cant use "joined_bill_pos" if you want use with out $unwind you have to use array notation like 'joined_bill_pos[0].pricelistItem.itemType'.After lookup the result will be stored in "joined_bill_pos" as array.To make it into object we will unwind the array using $unwind.